# textarea value is not shown in the area

Tags: javascript, html

I'm scratching my head on the following problem.

I have a tickbox. If it's ticked I show a textarea, with removing style by the below Javascript. At every page load the textarea is hidden with the data loaded between textarea tags. When user clicks on it, it should appear, which it doesn't do! When I inspect it with Firebug or Chrome I see the data where it is supposed to be. In Firebug if I add class="" on-the-fly it appears, but when I add this offline, so it will be present from the page load, it won't.

Sorry for being a little cryptic, this page is part of a bigger embedded webpage, not available on the internet.

Do you have any ideas?

HTML code:

```
<tr id="my_tr" style="display: none;">
<td colspan="2">
<div id="my_div">
<textarea cols="25" rows="3" name="my_textarea">initial data to be shown</textarea>
</div>
</td>
</tr>
```

---

JS code:

```
function show_hide_my_textarea() {
  var my_checkbox = $(tick_box_ref);
  var my_tr = document.getElementById("my_tr");

  if (my_checkbox.checked == true) {
      my_tr.style.display = '';
  } else {
      my_tr.style.display = 'none';
  }
}
```

UPDATE:
Ah sorry, I didn't explain it corretly. The textarea itself appears, but it remains empty.

Comment: Ah sorry, I didn't explain it corretly. The textarea itself appears, but it remains empty.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/jasper/CphV7/2/. This works for me in Firefox 7 & IE 9/8/7

Comment: Finally I have solved the whole problem with putting the "initial-data-to-be-shown" part into the Javascript, which solved the problem.

Otherwise the problem is most probably caused by too complex website.

Comment: Glad to hear it. So you are dynamically changing the `textarea`s `value`?

Comment: I'm only adding the initial value. If it is populated I don't touch it.

Answer (score 2):

```
if (my_checkbox.checked == true) {
    my_tr.style.display = 'table-row';
} else {
    my_tr.style.display = 'none';
}
```

Settings the display to nothing is invalid, try settings it to `table-row`.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/display

Comment: or `my_tr.style.display = (my_checkbox.checked ? 'table-row' : 'none');` ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Instead of setting `display` to nothing, set it to `table-row`:

```
my_tr.style.display = 'table-row';
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/display *<--Update*

Comment: *gasp* w3schools. I won't do the "that site stinks" comment like most do, but I would recommend [MDN's Write-Up on CSS display](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/display)

Comment: @BradChristie Yeah good call, Mozilla's docs are much better.

Comment: I have tried it but it doesn't do anything. Please see update at the end of question.

Answer (score 1):

```
my_tr.style.display = 'block';
```

Should do the trick

Answer (score 1):

Put in the first if:

```
my_tr.style.display = 'block';
```

instead of leaving it empty, and if it does not work, please paste the rest of the code :)

If it was display: none, you need to specify back display:block so it can be visible again, otherwise it will stay hidden.